# Error with the pytube module while attempting to do yt = YouTube(url)

Tags: python, pytube

I have a function called downloadSong which is used to download a song from youtube when given a url, but it's drawing an error

I've tried searching through a docs and the read me, but I haven't seen any mention of this error

```py
def downloadSong(url):
    yt = YouTube(str(url))
    video = yt.streams.first()
    downloadedVideo = video.download('/MusicCache')
    return downloadedVideo,yt.title
```

The expected result is for it to download the song, but instead it's drawing the error shown below:

````
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 859, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 725, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 's'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your use of pytube is fine, but there is a bug where if you do not specify a name for the file you want to save your youtube video to it crashes because pytube cannot create a default name. I had a similar problem.

Try this:

```
from pytube import Youtube

def downloadSong(url):
  yt = YouTube(str(url))
  video = yt.streams.first()
  downloadedVideo = video.download(output_path='/MusicCache', filename='MySong')
  return downloadedVideo, yt.title
```

If that doesn't work possibly try the absolute path to your folder you want to save your songs for the value of the `output_path` parameter in the `download()` function.